# How to display newly added element at the top of StackPanel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I add `UserControl` to `StackPanel` like this

```
public void AddEvent(UserControl uc)
{
    stackPanelMain.Children.Add(uc);
}
```

**But I would like to reorder them and display the last added element at the top.**

Is there a way to do it without let's say some `Dictionary<DateTime, UserControl>` and `foreach` to populate `Children` property of `stackPanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was ease as 2 x 2 :)

```
public void AddEvent(UserControl uc)
{
     stackPanelMain.Children.Insert(0, uc);
}
```